# WordPress виджет сохранение значения select

Tags: php, wordpress, виджет

Значения в Select (вижете) считываются с файла .json. После нажатия на кнопку "сохранить" запоминания не происходит.

Пишу так:

```
public function form($instance)
    {
        $jsonArray = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'suffix.json' ); 
        $array = json_decode($jsonArray);         
        $platform = isset($instance['platform']) ? $instance['platform'] : '';
        ?>
        <p>

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Platform:</label>
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('platform');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('platform');?>" type="text">
                <?php

                    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
                    { ?>
                        <option value="<?=$value?> <?php echo ($platform == $value)?'selected':'' ?>"><?=$key?></option>
                    <?php }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Никогда не используйте короткие теги: `<=` и `<? ` - не работают на большинстве серверов. Если понадобится перенести сайт, будут большие проблемы.

Comment: Где эта кнопка "Сохранить", что именно и куда вы хотите сохранить с её помощью?

Comment: Уже сделал...почему то при сравнении value и platform были различия и selected не присваивалось. В platform добавлялось то же value но только с пробелом в конце. Функция trim, и все заработало....спасибо за внимание всем.

Comment: @KAGG Design а разве это не в настройках самого сервера устанавливается? Я читал что это можно прописать...правда не использовал т к у меня работало всегда.

Comment: Можно, если эти настройки вам доступны. На shared хостингах они недоступны. По умолчанию настройки php не разрешают короткие теги. Именно по этой причине стандарты кодирования WordPress запрещают использовать короткие теги.

Comment: @KAGG Design Спасибо, учту